# Creating Environment using WSO2 APIMCLI tool

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

We have distributed environment as below and trying to export published API from the same.

- Identity Server as WSO2 KeyManager -> https://key-m:9443/carbon
- WSO2 Traffic and Publisher --> https://traffic:9443/carbon ,
  https://publisher:9444/carbon
- WSO2 Internal Gateway -->
  https://internal-gw:9443/carbon
- WSO2 External Gateway -->
  https://external-gw:9443/carbon
- WSO2 Store --> https://store:9443/carbon

*We have deployed "api-import-export-2.6.0-v14.war" in https://external-gw:9443/carbon and cli tool in the same server*

```
apimcli add-env -n dev \ --registration https://store:9443/client-registration/v0.14/register \ --apim https://external-gw:9443 \ --token https://key-m:9443/token \ --import-export https://external-gw:9443/api-import-export-2.6.0-v10 \ --admin https://external-gw:9443/api/am/admin/v0.14 \ --api_list https://publisher:9444/api/am/publisher/v0.14/apis \ --app_list https://store:9443/api/am/store/v0.14/applications
```

When we tried to login through cli tool to dev environment, we are getting "403:forbidden".

Suspecting while creating environment, we might have mis-configured urls for registration/apim/token/import-import/admin/api_list/app_list.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the `--registration https://https://key-m:9443/client-registration/v0.14/register` endpoint pointing to KM.

The API Import-export war should be deployed in Publisher node and provide `--import-export https://publisher:9443/api-import-export-2.6.0-v10` pointing to Publisher node.

`api#am#admin#v0.15.war` should be deployed to Publisher portal and provide `--admin https://publisher:9443/api/am/admin/v0.14` endpoint pointing to Publisher node.

Since you are providing the `api_list` and `app_list` flags it does not matter what value you provide for `apim`. Hence you can just point it to the Publisher node.